# Why doesn't the Vector.indexOf method work for this class?

Tags: java, vector, equals, indexof

I have a class exactly like this:

```
public class Operator {
        private String oper;
        private boolean ltr;
        private int pc;
        //Ignore these methods...
        public Operator(String t,int prc,boolean as) {oper=t;pc=-prc;ltr=as;}
        public int precedence() {return pc;}
        public boolean associativity() {return ltr;}
        public String getName() {return oper;}

    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 19 * hash + (this.oper != null ? this.oper.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 19 * hash + (this.ltr ? 1 : 0);
        hash = 19 * hash + this.pc;
        return hash;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (o instanceof String){
            return oper.equals(o);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return oper;
    }
}
```

when I do: `System.out.println(new Operator("+",4,true).equals("+"));` it prints true, which means that equals method is working.
but when I do this:

```
Vector oprs = new Vector();
oprs.addElement(new Operator("+",4,true));
int iof = oprs.indexOf("+");
System.out.println(iof);
```

iof is `-1`. Manual searching finds it well, and `System.out.println(oprs.elementAt(0));` prints `+`. I thought `indexOf` uses `equals` method to find the element (like in Java SE) so why on earth `oprs.indexOf` isn't working?

Comment: You _cannot_ pass a different type to `indexOf` from the contents of the list.  If you find yourself wanting to do that, write a proper `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of "+" is String. You can't redefine equality for the String class so your equals method is not reflexive. Check out the Comparator class. It (and the collection classes that use it) might help you.

Comment: The way you override hashCode is also incompatible with equals but if you use Comparator you can remove both methods, avoiding that problem.

Comment: idk, NetBeans IDE created `equals` and the `hashCode` for me so I'm not sure what is and what isn't wrong lol.

Comment: @SmRndGuy The incompatability that @JohnWatts refers to is that  that `op.equals("+")` returns true but `op.hashcode() != "+".hashcode()`.